# scriptdata not working in uploadify

Tags: php

Hi Friends i am using uploadify for my project.. in that i need to pass some data to upload.php to insert it in database. i am using the below code for sending data and getting it using $_POST in that upload.php file but its not getting those values.

```
    $("#fileupload").fileUpload({
        'uploader': 'uploadify/uploader.swf',
        'cancelImg': 'uploadify/cancel.png',
        'script': 'uploadify/upload.php',
        'scriptData' : {'name':'name','status':1}
```

Can anyone help me on this ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `scriptData`, not `scriptdata`. JavaScript is case sensitive in that regard.

Comment: yes i have changed that into scriptData.. but again its not working.. :( is that way of passing value is correct? and also the way of getting those value using $_POST is correct?

Comment: @Vinoth yes, that looks okay. Strange. I fixed the typo in your post; I will delete my answer soon.

Comment: yes Pekka, i used like this only, i did it again by copying ur edited code too.. but its not getting the values... :( i dont know where i did the mistake.. can u give any guess for the mistake which may often happen on this issue..(thanks for ur code)

Comment: @Vinoth what code are you using on server side to fetch the variables?

Comment: Pekka, its working now.... i used $_REQUEST now.. its working fine.. anyhow thanks for your response Pekka.... ur response helped me to change that scriptdata to scriptData :)

Comment: @Vinoth you're welcome, although that is really strange (The documentation says it's $_POST). Try whether it works with `$_GET`, it's better than using `$_REQUEST`

Comment: yes its working for $_GET too.. but its not working for $_POST. i dont know y.. ok i am using $_GET instead of $_REQUEST..